# Stack-driver metrics export

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

Environment: CloudShell
code : python2.7

I want to export Metrics from Cloud Monitoring to Big Query and google has given a solution on how to do this. I am following this in this below article:
**https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export**

I have downloaded the code from github: `https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-metrics-export` and I am following the readme and trying to run the application in my google project.

When I install and run any of the app engines ex
`https://get-timeseries-dot-managed-gcp.uc.r.appspot.com/`/, I always get this error 500:

Error: Server Error

```
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

In the logs i check and i get his

```
  0: {
    logMessage: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myproject/get-timeseries:20200623t152416.427592472816201321/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
ImportError: No module named googleapiclient.discovery"     
    severity: "ERROR"     
    sourceLocation: {
     file: "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/534e28e62871e9ae/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/cgi.py"      
     functionName: "HandleRequest"      
     line: "123"      
    }
    time: "2020-06-23T10:04:42.365030Z"     
   }
   1: {
    logMessage: "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."     
    severity: "INFO"     
    time: "2020-06-23T10:04:42.368883Z"     
   }
   2: {
    logMessage: "The warmup request failed. Please check your warmup handler implementation and make sure it's working correctly."     
    severity: "INFO"     
    time: "2020-06-23T10:04:42.368884Z"     
   }
   3: {
    logMessage: "Process terminated because it failed to respond to the start request with an HTTP status code of 200-299 or 404."     
    severity: "ERROR"     
    time: "2020-06-23T10:04:42.368885Z"     
   }
  ]
  megaCycles: "241"   
  method: "GET"   
  moduleId: "get-timeseries"   
  requestId: "5ef1d3b500ff0ef7c1e4b283290001737e6d616e616765642d67637000016765742d74696d657365726965733a323032303036323374313532343136000100"   
  resource: "/_ah/start"   
  startTime: "2020-06-23T10:04:37.980929Z"   
  status: 500   
  traceId: "cc847beddcfade8728ae864d45761acd"   
  traceSampled: true   
  urlMapEntry: "main.py"   
  versionId: "20200623t152416"   
  wasLoadingRequest: true
```

. In app engine console the application is running in the services tab

Another issue is if i try to create a  pub-sub subscription from cloudshellas mentioned in the source code like this after creating the topic:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions create metrics_export_start_sub --topic metrics_export_start --ack-deadline=60 --message-retention-duration=10m --push-endpoint="$LIST_METRICS_URL/_ah/push-handlers/receive_message"
```

I get this error even if i provide the project id also:

```
The supplied app engine url project does not match the subscription's parent project
```

Because of the above error I am not able to complete the pubsub subscriptions. i searched and ran this also

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

I am using python 2.7 version and after installing the above still i am getting

```
No module named googleapiclient.discovery
```

Has anyone tried to use this code previously? I am totally new to google cloud and also to python.
Kindly help

Comment: Could you please share the format of `$LIST_METRICS_URL`? It looks like Pub/Sub currently does not play well with regional AppEngine endpoints in some situations, which might be what you are running into. If you have a URL like `https://my-project-id.aa.b.appspot.com`, try replacing it with `https://my-project-id.appspot.com`.

Comment: https://get-timeseries-dot-myproject.uc.r.appspot.com if i replace this url with https://get-timeseries-dot-myproject.appspot.com still it does not work and get 404 error

Comment: LIST_METRICS_URL format https://list-metrics-dot-myproject.uc.r.appspot.com

Comment: For any future readers, Pub/Sub now supports creating push subscriptions to regional AppEngine endpoints.

Comment: Hi I am frequently getting this error when write_metrics application is writing to the database  @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"   
  appEngineRelease: "1.9.71"   
  appId: "s~managed-prj"   
  endTime: "2020-07-22T17:25:46.822457Z"   
  finished: true   
  first: true   
  host: "write-metrics-dot-managed-prj.appspot.com"   
  latency: "10.985283s"   
  line: [
   0: {
    logMessage: "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."     
    severity: "ERROR"     
    time: "2020-07-22T17:25:46.822446Z"     
   }

Comment: Lauren: can you pls help in this regard i am using this application for collecting metrics. It is frequently giving me 500 error even if set interval of 86400s as aggregate alignment period and start collecting from July 1st of this month. In app.yaml for write metrics i have set to automatic scaling: automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 5
  max_instances: 25
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 50. but no effect

Comment: Also frequently I am getting this error also; While handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the region_id and the "r" from the App Engine URL captured in LIST_METRICS_URL will allow you to create the Pub/Sub subscription.

The github repo README.md has been updated to reflect the changes in handling of the region_id in App Engine which is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/communicating-between-services).

As an example, the LIST_METRICS_URL is either

```
# if this is your first app in your project
export LIST_METRICS_URL=https://$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

OR

```
# if this is not your first app in your project
export LIST_METRICS_URL=https://list-metrics-dot-$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am facing this issue. On deploying any of the 3 apps write_metrics,list_metrics,timseries this error come when I change on the url in both forms  
 https://list-metrics-dot-my-project.appspot.com/ or   https://list-metrics-dot-my-project.appspot.uc.r.com/  Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Comment: from the logs line: [
   0: {
    logMessage: "No handlers matched this URL."     
    severity: "WARNING"     
    time: "2020-06-24T14:32:29.971283Z"     
   }
this error is avoided only if i modify the app.yaml and create static/images folder
 and add this code under handlers -                                                                              
 url: /
 static_files: static/images/favicon.ico.                                                                             
 upload: static/images/favicon.ico   Can this be avoided as here i have to upload a image

Comment: I am totally new to google cloud and python ,so require your inputs here.Thanks

Comment: The "Error: Not Found" is expected because the code is specifically targeted towards receiving the push notification from Cloud Pub/Sub as the trigger and doesn't define a "/" target to receive requests.

Comment: If you have deployed the Cloud Scheduler job, you can run the job by using the "gcloud scheduler jobs run metric_export" listed under the "Run the tests" section of the github README.md.

Comment: Hi, can you pls tell me the purpose of handlers /_ah/start and /_ah/stop I see that in _ah/start this method is written set_last_end_time but the same message is also written in ah/push-handlers/receive_message also the  _ah/start and _ah/stop gets executed after the ah/push-handlers/receive_message , I m not understanding that, can you please explain?

Comment: I am frequently getting this error. Can you pls helpWhile handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application or may be using an instance with insufficient memory. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.

Comment: for write metrics i have set to automatic scaling: automatic_scaling: target_cpu_utilization: 0.65 min_instances: 5 max_instances: 25 min_pending_latency: 30ms max_pending_latency: automatic max_concurrent_requests: 50. but no effect –