# Google Cloud alerting condition on missing infrequent event

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to create an alert condition where if an infrequent event (e.g. cron job running once a week) does not occur, it will trigger.

The metric is [log-based](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics). I've had success with smaller windows by using the alignment period, but there is a limitation where the alignment period can not be longer than 1 day.

> Alignment periods longer than 86400 seconds are not supported.

(Not working) sample of what I'm trying to do:

```yaml
- conditionThreshold:
    aggregations:
    - alignmentPeriod: 604800s # 1 week NOT possible
      perSeriesAligner: ALIGN_SUM
    comparison: COMPARISON_LT
    thresholdValue: 1.0
    duration: 0s
    filter: metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/my_infrequent_event_count"
    trigger:
      count: 1
  displayName: Infrequent event did not occur
```

Any idea on how this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible to accomplish as the duration can’t exceed from 24h.
As a workaround, you might find useful [Cloud Monitoring metric export](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export) for long-term metrics analysis. Please also refer to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/how-to-use-stackdriver-monitoring-export-for-long-term-metric-analysis).

I found [this public thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512711/stack-driver-metrics-export), which might be helpful too.

Comment: how would I alert on an exported metric? Are you suggesting I use a different monitoring system?

Comment: With the [exported metric](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export#using_the_exported_metrics) data in BigQuery, you can now use standard SQL to query the data or build dashboards to visualize trends in your metrics over time. [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/stackdriver-monitoring-metric-export#using_the_exported_metrics) also described different use cases for metric export.